# How to define variable in OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

```
<div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-telephone1">Confirm Telephone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="tel" name="telephone1" value="" placeholder="Confirm Telephone" id="input-telephone1" class="form-control" required/>

 <?php if ($error_telephone1) { ?>

              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_telephone1; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I am getting an error message even though I have already defined a variable in language and controller. Error message is given below:

**errorNotice: Undefined variable: error_telephone1 in /home/chaarms/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/register.tpl on line 85**

Comment: Which version of **Opencart** are you using?

Answer (score 0):

in corresponding controller file, in your case catalog/controller/account/register.php you should define it:

```
$data['error_telephone1'] = "some code where  from you want to get this info";
```

for example if you want to add some text code should  be next:

```
$data['error_telephone1'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone1');
```

and in corresponding language file add:

```
$_['error_telephone1']               = 'Telephone error!!!';
```

that's all.